# HWK Help: Conditional Probability Proof

Tags: probability-theory

So I've been working on this proof (and most likely making harder than it is) for quite some time now and I am getting nowhere.

The proof is the following: Let $A_{k}$ be the event that the animal makes the desired response on the $kth$ day, and suppose that $P(A_{k+1}|A_{k})$ = $\beta$ and $P(A_{k+1}|A'_{k})$ = $\alpha$ , where 0<$\alpha$<$\beta$$\leq$1.

Show if $\beta$ = 1 and $p_{1}$ = 0, show that $p_{k}$ = 1 - (1 - $\alpha$)$^{k-1}$

I am new to LaTex code and very slow, so I am not going to show all of my steps. Needless to say, all of my steps are wrong. I am just looking for some advice to at least get me on track. The proof before this exercise may contain a clue that I am not seeing.

Let $p_{k}$ = P($A_{k}$). Show that $p_{k+1}$ = $\alpha$ + ($\beta$ - $\alpha$)$p_{k}$

Comment: what is $A_k'$?

Comment: The complement of $A_{k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\beta = 1$, we know that $P(A_{k+i}|A_k)= 1$ for $i \geq 1$. In other words $p_k$ is the probability that the event $A_i$ has happened for some $i \leq k$. Therefore
$$
p_k = 1-P(A_1', A_2', \dots, A_k').
$$
Now, since $ P(A_{k+1}'|A_k')  =1-P(A_{k+1}|A_k') = 1-\alpha$,
$$
P(A_1', A_2', \dots, A_k')  =1 \cdot (1-\alpha)^{k-1}
$$
(the $1$ coming from $P(A_1')=1$). Putting this together you have your formula.

Btw: Here I have supposed that $P(A_1', A_2', \dots, A_k') = P(A_k'|A'_{k-1}) \cdot P(A_{k-1}'|A'_{k-2}) \cdots P(A_2'|A_1')$ which you might wanna prove by induction.

Comment: Ah, I see. I definitely wasn't taking that approach. I was able to get the proof of the other exercise to work and have been trying to prove it in a similar fashion but with no success. Thank you very much!